# How to delete gmail contacts from contacts app in Gingerbread

Tags: contacts, sync

My phone is a Samsung Galaxy Y phone. I do not want my Gmail contacts in the phone contacts. I have disabled automatic sync. There seems to be no direct way to delete them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To completely remove them from device, go into:

```
Settings -> Accounts and sync -> (select your account) -> Turn "Sync Contacts" off
```

Now delete Gmail contacts from your phone:

1. Use the method @Ames suggested to filter out Gmail contacts only
2. Delete all contacts (only Gmail ones will get deleted)
3. Revert to displaying other contacts.

Since Contacts will not be synced, this will neither delete your contacts from web version of Gmail nor bring them back to your device. Just be careful not to turn this setting back on.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the firmware, but try this:

- While viewing contacts select menu button and then More
- Display Options
- Under "Select contacts to display" uncheck the Gmail contacts.

Comment: Of course, strictly speaking, that doesn't _delete_ them; it merely prevents them from being displayed.

Comment: I want to delete it though. Though I hide them, when adding a phone number to the contacts, it still shows the Gmail contacts.